# Find/Replace cells in selected range having zero values (Formula cells) using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How can i use "Find/Replace" (Or any other alternative if available except for loops) in VBA to replace cells in selected range with "0" to "1".

Note: All cells in selected range are formula based, their resultant value will be "0".

Thanks,
Prasanna M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Post Your Comments: Without Loops**

**Using Evaluate over the Range.** As Per [Here](https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/06/19/avoid-loop-for-range-calculations-evaluate/).

for **unwrapped values:**

```
  Sub Test2()

  Dim rngData     As Range
    
  Set rngData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:G650000")
  rngData = Evaluate("Substitute(" & rngData.Address & "," & "0" & ", " & "1" & ")")
   End Sub
```

for **wrapped values:**

```
Sub Test3()

Dim rngData     As Range


Set rngData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:G650000")
rngData = Evaluate("Substitute(" & rngData.Address & "," & "Char(34)&" & "0" & "& Char(34)" & ", " & "Char(34) &" & "1" & "& Char(34)" & ")")
End Sub
```

I seems to work very well. I ran over 650000 rows, B to G, in a under 3 Seconds first time, under 10 seconds the 2nd time (i have other things running as well). 3rd, 4th & 5th time entire range was `=CHAR(34)&RANDBETWEEN(0,1)&CHAR(34)`, 4th and 4th Generated random 0,1's over the range with formula, 5th  was a choose randbetwen function and lookup, 6th a lookup against a table in another sheet. It Always did the find-replace in under 15 secs. I do not think the formulas you have in your sheet matter to the macro. Its looking at values only, and changing values. Its the depth and length of your range that matters to it more.

I note also; going by your previous question, you could build in your conditions in there: to change the 0's to 1's , only if/when the values in range A are 'Def' as opposed to 'abc', so it all runs from the vba sub (but you will loose your formulae *unless you build *those* in that too*).

**3rd Proposed alternative soln:**

Assign unique serial numbers or id's by row to the entire table, filter DEF by column A, copy/strip those Def rows out to Sheet 2, find-replace 0 to 1 there , cut/delete original Defs rows, paste sheet2's Defs in sheet 1. Sort by id.  Job done. 1 min that would take. ok, maybe 2.

Comment: Thanks Spyros, The above code works. Is there any other way of doing without using loops. I have huge collections of cells linked to the cells in question with formula attached to it, hence looping through each cells is really taking enormous time.

Comment: I have always found in instances llke this, doing something like the following is faster and more stable ,=SUBSTITUTE('Sheet1 (2)'!D19,CHAR(34)&"0"&CHAR(34),CHAR(34)&"1"&CHAR(34)) & im sorry , I did't pay attention your "without loops" bit,

Comment: There is a way to do it - describes same issue here - with evaluate, https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/06/19/avoid-loop-for-range-calculations-evaluate/

Comment: Ok, I just ran the test subs/codes below over ranges B1 to G 650000 rows. Took no more than 3 seconds.

Comment: Ran the evaluate over range method 5-7  times. over Range B1:G650000.filled with formulas making 0 (including Randomly Generated 0,1 but also lookups). Got the conversion to 1 or "1" done in under 15 seconds each time.

Comment: I've changed my answer further to your comments. Maybe it works better for you now?

Comment: How does this compare, efficiency wise, with using `rngData.Replace "0", "1"`, instead of `rngData = Evaluate("Substitute(" & rngData.Address & "," & "0" & ", " & "1" & ")")`?

Comment: Thank you for the help, Spyros. I got to see evaluate is faster than using loops. I have also disabled automatic calculation (Application.Calculation = xlManual) before and enabling it back. Which increased the code run exponentially.